# Multiple Choice Questions in Exam package

Tags: exam

I am trying to write an exam with some multiple choice questions. Here is a minimal example of what I am doing

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\gradetable
\end{center}


\begin{questions}

\titledquestion{\textbf{Multiple Choice}}[10]


What is the Capital of the United States in 1799?

\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice NY 
\CorrectChoice Washington D.C.
\choice Chicago
\choice LA

\end{oneparchoices}




\question[10]

What is the Capital of the United Kinddom in 1999?

\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice London 
\CorrectChoice Washington D.C.
\choice Chicago
\choice LA

\end{oneparchoices}


\end{questions}



\end{document}
```

I would like to achieve the following:

1. The choices are really close to each other, it there a way to put them in the full line with equal spaces between them?
2. I would like to start count the questions from the second one, how do I achieve this?

Comment: Do you have to use the addpoints document class?  Any time you use a package you make things easier to do it their way, but almost impossible to do it any other way.

Comment: Sorry for not understanding, but what does the 2nd question mean?

Comment: @karlkoeller I think OP means that they don't want the first exam question numbered - the second should be `1`, and so on. (Possibly the first is a practice question or something.)

Answer (score 4):

1) I used `xpatch` to fix the amount of space after each choice.

2) I renewed the `\questionlabel` command for the first question. `\phantom{}` reserves the space of the question number but it is not printed. I reset it it back to the class default before the section question.

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{xpatch}

% Need both to patch both instances (choice, correctchoice) in the oneparchoices environment.
% Unless there is a global replacement that works within an environment. I don't know.
% Replaces \hskip 1em with \hfill
\xpatchcmd{\oneparchoices}{\penalty -50\hskip 1em plus 1em\relax}{\hfill}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\oneparchoices}{\penalty -50\hskip 1em plus 1em\relax}{\hfill}{}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\gradetable
\end{center}
\begin{questions}

\renewcommand\questionlabel{\phantom{\thequestion.}}
\titledquestion{\textbf{Multiple Choice}}[10]
What is the Capital of the United States in 1799?

\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice NY
\CorrectChoice Washington D.C.
\choice Chicago
\choice LA
\end{oneparchoices}

\renewcommand\questionlabel{\thequestion.}
%\setcounter{question}{0}   %Uncomment if you want the first numbered question to start at 1.

\question[10]
What is the Capital of the United Kinddom in 1999?

\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice London 
\CorrectChoice Washington D.C.
\choice Chicago
\choice Los Angeles
\end{oneparchoices}

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]